# How to use amountToPrecision ccxt library

Tags: javascript, cryptocurrency, ccxt

I have quite hard time to understand how to use this.
I'm playing with testing account, and succeeded to "buy" xrp with my usdt like this:
NOTE: I use binance, and my orders is based on quote price.

```
   params = {
        'quoteOrderQty': 20,
    }
    const order = await binance.createOrder('XRP/USDT', 'market', 'buy', null, null, params)
    order.push(order)
```

later, I tried to sell my xrp for usdt, by I keep getting precision error:

> binance order amount should be evenly divisible by lot size

And I read that the `amountToPrecision`  is the answet, but I didn't get yet how to use this.

I tried like this without any success:

```
params = {
    'quoteOrderQty': binance.amountToPrecision('XRP/USDT', 20),
}
const order = await binance.createOrder('XRP/USDT', 'market', 'sell', null, null, params)
```

Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I used this, passing amount and price on the signature of the createOrder method:

```
let formattedAmount = binance.amountToPrecision(symbol, amount);
let formattedPrice = binance.priceToPrecision(symbol, price);
let order = await binance.createOrder(symbol, type, side, formattedAmount, formattedPrice, params);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me as it should. Given I want to buy ETH for $100 while ETH price is `1573.63`, I should have `0.06354733959062804` of ETH, instead it formats me to `0.06354` which at the end is worth of $99.9884502 instead of $100 as planned

Comment: The exchange doesnt allow you do go to that precision the functions provided in CCXT trucate to those limitations.